# Can i upload an iPA with lower build number?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I have uploaded an IPA with below details:

```
version - 1.0.4
build - 1.0.4
```

the above IPA is in my Activity section in iTunes connect.

My question is can I upload an IPA with below detail:

```
version - 1.0.5
**build - 1.0**
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

YES You can do it, if the app **version** is changed from **1.0.4** to **1.0.5** than you can set the **build** version to **1.0**

Answer (score 0):

It's allowed with `iOS`, although `macOS` it is not.

All of the builds that you provide for a particular version of your app is called that version's "release train" (eg. 1.0.4, 1.0.5, etc). For `iOS` Apps you can use the same build numbers again in different release trains if you want to.

> For `macOS` apps, build numbers must monotonically increase even across
>   different versions. In other words, for macOS apps you cannot use the
>   same build numbers again in different release trains. `iOS` apps have
>   no such restriction and you can re-use the same build numbers again in
>   different release trains.

↳ [Version Numbers and Build Numbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2420/_index.html)